# How to set dynamic Subject body in email message body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hey i am trying to send mail, and here is code in c#

```
 objEmail.Subject = string.Format("Questionnaire={0}",Request.QueryString["orgname"]);
```

but `+Request.QueryString["orgname"]";` not working

and its exact link

Questionnaire Test org

"Test org" is Dynamic according to user

Answer (score 1):

Your string concatenation is wrong. You attemp to add your `Request.QueryString["ID"]` as a part of string, not a variable. You can use;

```
string MsgBody = "https://example.com/Coordinator/Questionnaire.aspx?OnsiteRequest=" + Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

or you can [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) like;

```
string MsgBody = string.Format("https://example.com/Coordinator/Questionnaire.aspx?OnsiteRequest={0}", 
                                Request.QueryString["ID"]);
```